# PROPERTY_REMOVED_FROM_CLOSED_CONTENT_MODEL for optional field

Tags: json, kotlin, jsonschema, backwards-compatibility, confluent-schema-registry

Use draft-7 json schema CLOSED_CONTENT_MODEL and BACKWARD compatibility and confluent schema registry 7.2.1-post.

```
deps:
    implementation 'com.github.victools:jsonschema-generator:4.26.0'
    implementation 'io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry:7.2.1'
```

schema example

```json
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "description" : "String"
      },
      "timeDescription" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "description" : "String"
      },
    },
    "required" : [ "name"],
    "additionalProperties" : false
}
```

I am trying to find incompatibilities between schema via
{{base_url}}/compatibility/subjects/subject/versions/latest?verbose=true
(**timeDescription is absent but not required**)

````json
{
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
      "name" : {
        "type" : "string",
        "description" : "String"
      },
    },
    "required" : [ "name"],
    "additionalProperties" : false
}

and see 
```json
{
    "is_compatible": false,
    "messages": [
        "Found incompatible change: Difference{jsonPath='#/properties/timeDescription', type=PROPERTY_REMOVED_FROM_CLOSED_CONTENT_MODEL}"
    ]
}
````

How to disable incompatibilities for case when optional field exists in one schema and absent in another?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to enable or disable compatibilities. You might need select different  [Schema type](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/avro.html#compatibility-types).

Comment: You mean I should set different Compatibility Type or set it to NONE which mean disable compatibility checks at all. Not schema type because schema types are JSON, AVRO or PROTOBUF.

Comment: Your questions can be dived in: 1 Compare the schemas, 2 Send only required data

Comment: 1 Compare the schemas. It is not possible to disable fields when try to compare schemas. Then your option is to disable compatibility setting it to NONE

Comment: 2 Send only required data. You can send only required json values with to the topic using BACKWARD. But I see the your schema example needs to set defaults to non-required fields

Answer (score 0):

The default rules for JSON schema compatibility implemented in Confluent's Schema Registry don't allow optional properties to be added or removed from a closed content model.

See Creek's [post on why this is](https://www.creekservice.org/articles/2024/01/08/json-schema-evolution-part-1.html), this goes into this in some detail, plus links to other posts with more details, and the second post in the series explains how to implement more useful compatibility checks.